# how to compare word letters using if statements?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, charat

I'm trying to write a program that reads a word and prints if:

- it ends with the letter y.
- has the same first and last character, ignoring case.

This is what I have so far, but I'm having trouble thinking of a line of code that will check individual letters or compare the first and last letters.

```
  if (. . .)
  {
     System.out.println(word + " ends in a y");
  }

  if (. . .)
  {
     System.out.println(word + " starts and ends with the same letter");
  }
```

Comment: How about `charAt`?

Comment: Start by looking at [the API for the String class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 1):

String has an [`endsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) method.

```
if (word.endsWith("y") || word.endsWith("Y")) {
    System.out.println(word + " ends with y");
}
```

You can get a character from the string using [`charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)), as long as the string is not empty. You can convert a character to upper case using [`Character.toUpperCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase(char)) so that you can compare characters without worrying about what case they are in.

```
if (word.length() > 0 && Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0))==Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(word.length()-1))) {
    System.out.println(word + " starts and ends with the same letter.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your code helped make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.endsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) for both:

```
// To ignore case, just lower all
word = word.toLowerCase();
// Check if it ends with 'y'
if (word.endsWith("y"))
// Check if it starts and ends with same letter
if (word.endsWith(word.substring(0,1)))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score -1):

Consider a word hello in your string.  You can get the word length easily with word.length() this will return 5 for "Hello"

With another method called charAt(int position) you can get the  character at the given position.

System.out.println(String.valueOf(word.charAt(0))); //The result is H
System.out.println(String.valueOf(word.charAt(4))); //The result is o

4 is the length of word minus one so try finding it dynamically for all the word this way:

```
String.valueOf((word.length()-1))
```

If you had two string you can compare them with:

```
string1.equals(string2)
```

this will return true if they are the same and false if they are not.

Below is the full source code:

```
    String word = "Hello";

    //no if is needed for the first one
    println(word + " ends with letter " + word.charAt(word.length()-1) + ".");


   if (String.valueOf(word.charAt(0)).equals(String.valueOf(word.charAt(word.length()-1)))) {
        println(word + " starts and ends with the same letter.");
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope you change your mind and mark my answer as a helpful solution.

Comment: Perhaps you should try and compile this code and then fix the problems.